# New instance of data class with reflection

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I am creating a new data class instance with reflection. Is there a better solution than the code below?

```
private inline fun <reified TEntity : Any> queryMapping(params: MultiValueMap<String, String>): TEntity {
    val entity = TEntity::class
    var resultInstance = entity.createInstance()

    params.forEach { param ->

        val property = entity.memberProperties.find { member ->
            member.name.toLowerCase() == param.key.toLowerCase() }

        if (property is KMutableProperty<*>) {
            when(property.returnType.javaType.typeName.toLowerCase()) {
                "int" -> property.setter.call(resultInstance, param.value.first().toInt())
                "java.lang.string" -> property.setter.call(resultInstance, param.value.first())
            }
        }
    }

    return resultInstance
}
```

In this case data class properties has to be mutable (var).
Example data class:

```
data class PostPerson(
        var Id: Int = 0,
        var Name: String = "",
        var Age: Int = 0)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Since the caller must know the type at compile-time, why can't it just call the constructor directly?  (As well as being faster, simpler, and more robust, that gives you much more help in your IDE and more compile-time checking.  Reflection is a necessary tool for plug-ins, frameworks, and compile-time tools; but it's rarely a good solution for general application programming in a strongly-typed language like Kotlin.)

Comment: Assuming you have a good reason to be doing this, that is a fair amount of code to inline. I would remove reification and add a constructor parameter `constructor: () -> T` for creating the instance. Then you can pass the constructor like this: `queryMapping(::PostPerson, params)`.

Comment: @gidds Hi, yes I can create an object directly from the parameters, but I wanted to automate it in some way. At least that's how I would do it in C #, which is my primary language, and I'm still a little confused about how reflection works in Java / Kotlin.